# If Google Play Games Services offer Real-time Multiplayer, what is the advantage of using gamesparks.com? What is the difference between these two?

Tags: android, gamesparks, real-time-multiplayer

I am new to Android Game development and searching for a suitable backend for a real-time multiplayer interaction.

I found out that there is the Real-time Multiplayer offered by Google, then there are services like gamesparks and playfab (and google firebase).

What are the advantages of using gamesparks over Google's Real-time Multiplayer?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gamesparks supports cross-platform while real-time multiplayer offered by google only for android platform.

Gamesparks are great but limit 5000 api request per MAU (monthly active user), you want more you got to pay.
https://www.gamesparks.com/fair-usage-policy/